# How to properly access tabBarController in this nested flow?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` as a `rootViewController`, which in turns eventually has `UITabBarController` pushed to the top of the stack.

The `UITabBarController` has 2 pages. Each of the pages has `UINavigationController` as the root, let say this is `UINavigationController` A and B.

Each of A and B has a UIViewController as the root. Let's say this is C and D.

Now I'm working on the class `UIViewController` C. I want to get a reference to the `UITabBarController` from C. So I do these:

- `self.tabBarController`
- `self.navigationController?.tabBarController`

All of these returns nil. How can I get the reference to the `UITabBarController` object?

Comment: Where in your view controller are you trying to access the tab controller? Both of your attempts should work if called in the right place.

Comment: post the code where you are adding controller C to UITabBarController

Comment: @rmaddy yes, from what I read on the internet, it should be, but surprisingly I get nil for both code.

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh I use storyboard to put `UINavigationControllers` and `UIViewControllers` into the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: @ChenLiYong You did not answer my question. Where is this code?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience for such hierarchy simply go the other way, start from the top.

With such architecture I assume you are expecting to have one view controller that will always be on top which in your case is navigation controller. I would add some code to support "main instance" procedure:

```
static var mainInstance: TopNavigationController!

func viewDidLoad() {
    // super...
    TopNavigationController.mainInstance = self
    // ...
}
```

Now through it it might be less chaotic to access your tab bar view controller:

```
if let tabBarController = TopNavigationController.mainInstance.myTabBarViewController {
    // Do stuff
}
```

In your case I would go even deeper and create a "current instance" procedure on your tab bar view controller. This still assumes that only one instance will be loaded at the same time but it is not expected to always exist. It is not much of a difference:

```
static weak var currentInstance: MyTabBarViewController? // We want it weak so it is released if we navigate back from it

func viewDidLoad() {
    // super...
    MyTabBarViewController.currentInstance = self
    // ...
}
```

These are a bit lazy procedures but are great for many solutions and can save you loads of time in situations like deep linking.

But if this is not possible and you in general simply need to access these elements (can be multiple controllers) without using static properties then still rather send a delegate or a concrete class down the pipeline:

For instance if a tab bar view controller needs to execute something that is triggered down the hierarchy you can simply do something like:

```
let controller = SomeController()
controller.ownerTabBarController = self
self.navigationControllerAtIndex(1).push(controller...
```

Then `SomeController` obviously has a weak property:

```
weak var ownerTabBarController: MyTabBarViewController?
```

and can do:

```
ownerTabBarController?.executeSomeMethod()
```

I hope this gives you some ideas on how to better create messaging between view controllers. Any of these procedures should work even if you later change hierarchy (which easily happens).